# Filter by input date sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to filter a query result by date using the dd-MM-YY format as input, when I run the query it gives me the empty table, how can I solve?

```
select Data, string_agg(Ore, '  ') as Ore 
from ( 
   select FORMAT(DataCreazione, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'it-IT') as Data,
          CONCAT(DATEPART(HOUR,DataCreazione), ':', DATEPART(MINUTE, DataCreazione)) as
Ore 
   from Marcatura 
   where IdUtente = @IdUtente 
    and (Stato='Ingresso' or Stato='Uscita') 
     and (CONVERT(datetime, DataCreazione, 103) 
        between CONVERT(datetime, @Start, 103) 
            and CONVERT(datetime, @End, 103))
) t 
group by Data 
order by CONVERT(datetime, Data, 103) desc
    ​
```

**INPUT VALUE:**

```
@IdUtente=2
@End='14-09-19'
@Start='05-02-19'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your start and end date are all valid SQL format. You can cast it to datetime, but we need to tell SQL which format is your original date.

```
cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(date, @Start, 5), 23)  as datetime)
```

**complete query:**

```
select Data, string_agg(Ore, '  ') as Ore 
from ( 
   select FORMAT(DataCreazione, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'it-IT') as Data,
          CONCAT(DATEPART(HOUR,DataCreazione), ':', DATEPART(MINUTE, DataCreazione)) as
Ore 
   from Marcatura 
   where IdUtente = @IdUtente 
    and (Stato='Ingresso' or Stato='Uscita') 
     and cast(DataCreazion as DateTime)
        between cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(date, @Start, 5), 23)  as datetime)
            and  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(date, @End, 5), 23)  as datetime)
) t 
group by Data 
order by CONVERT(datetime, Data, 5) desc
```

Comment: always gives me the empty table

Comment: always gives me the empty table

Comment: try now, your dates are valid. but we need to tell sql which format to use.

Comment: just work change CONVERT(datetime, Data, 5) to CONVERT(datetime, Data, 105)

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can set connection level property like below.

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;

SELECT Data
    ,string_agg(Ore, '  ') AS Ore
FROM (
    SELECT FORMAT(DataCreazione, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'it-IT') AS Data
        ,CONCAT (DATEPART(HOUR, DataCreazione),':',DATEPART(MINUTE, DataCreazione)) AS Ore
    FROM Marcatura
    WHERE IdUtente = @IdUtente
        AND (Stato = 'Ingresso' OR Stato = 'Uscita')
        AND (
              DataCreazione  BETWEEN   @Start and @End 
            )
    ) t
GROUP BY Data
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, Data, 103) DESC
```